# Expo fails to build, Request failed with status code 400

Tags: react-native, build, expo

I'm trying to build a project in expo react native project.

My expo version is 3.2.2, sdkVersion is 35.

When I ran in cmd (on Windows 10)

```
set EXPO_DEBUG=true
expo build:android -c
```

I got:

```
Request failed with status code 400

Error: Request failed with status code 400
  at createError (C:\Users\Jonny\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
  at settle (C:\Users\Jonny\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:17:12)
  at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (C:\Users\Jonny\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:237:11)
  at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
  at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

I'm tried to update expo version, sdkVersion, the version in react, check for internet connection.

Expo login and logout works fine. I don't have any proxy in my network.

I don't have any clues for what search or how to fix this problem.

Comment: Can you try remove -c or try with previous version npm install -g expo-cli@3.2.0

Comment: As a temporary solution, I downgraded to expo-cli 3.1.0 and it ran the build. I tried 3.2.0 and some other versions that didn't work and gave me the 400.

Comment: Same error with same expo cli version 3.2.2 (skd 33) for me. I will give it a try with downgrade to 3.1.0.

Comment: expo-cli@3.2.3 on Mac fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems was a error in `expo-cli` version `3.2.2`.

The update `3.2.3` fixed for me.

Answer (score 3):

I have fixed the issue by using this command

Move to your root folder then type this command in your terminal

**npm install -g expo-cli**

Comment: Thanks, updating `expo-cli` also fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had two versions of expo-cli installed (one via `yarn global install expo-cli` and one as a dev dependency in project `yarn add -D expo-cli`). This started working for me after I removed the global expo-cli:
`yarn global remove expo-cli`
and used the local version in my project instead:
`yarn run expo-cli start`

Answer (score 0):

Run those following command, then we are good to go.

```
$ yarn global remove expo-cli && yarn global add expo-cli

$ rm -rf node_modules/ yarn.lock  && yarn install

$ yarn run start
```